# Accessing the file written using Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

i have created a file using Cordova file API in worklight. i wnat to read the file once the write event is done. I tried writing the function call readAsText() in the writer.onwriteend event. But the file is not being read.  Does the "exclusive" option have something to do with this? Everything works fine till read(), and then there is no error, no message.. but i think it is not reading the file. But once an error occurred on **reader.onloadend event** :

> read error
>   {"type":"error","bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"lengthComputable":false,"loaded":0,"total":0,"target":{"fileName":"file://C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\cordova\filesystem\persistent\RQM\ExecutionResult.xml","readyState":2,"result":null,"error":{"code":1},"onloadstart":null,"onprogress":null,"onload":null,"onabort":null}}

Here is my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        onFileSystemSuccess, fail);


function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
alert("Created File system ");
fileSystem.root.getFile("ExecutionResult.xml", {
    create : true,
    exclusive : true
}, gotFileEntry, fail);
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
writer.write(JsonData);

writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
    readAfterWriting();
};
}
function readAfterWriting(){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("ExecutionResult.xml", {
        create : false,
        exclusive : false
    }, gotFile, fail);

};
} 
function gotFile(file) {
readAsText(file);
}
function readAsText(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("Read as text");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

This is the code where the error is occuring. The file name is shown as 22. 
here is the line shown.. **var callbackId = v.id;**

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    _consoleLog("*****PG BC***** " + e.domain + " said: " + e.data);
    var r = e.data;

    // If a result was returned
    _consoleLog("typeof result=" + (typeof r) + " r=" + r);
    if (r.length > 0) {
        // if ((typeof r == "string") && (r.length > 0)) {
        _consoleLog("Result from exec=<" + dumpObj(r, '', ' ', 2) + ">");
        eval("var v=" + r + ";");
        var callbackId = v.id;
        var cast = v.cast;
        // var temp = "+cast+"("+this.getJSONString() + ");\n"
        if (cast) {
            // _consoleLog("CAST==="+"var
            // temp="+cast+"("+JSON.stringify(v.message)+");\n");
            // eval("var temp="+cast+"("+JSON.stringify(v.message)+");\n");
            // _consoleLog("***** CAST:"+" var temp="+cast+"("+r+");");
            eval("var temp=" + cast + "(" + r + ");");
            v = temp;
        }
        // _consoleLog("After CAST="+dumpObj(v, '', ' ', 3));

        // If status is OK, then return value back to caller
        if (v.status === Cordova.callbackStatus.OK) {

            // If there is a success callback, then call it now with
            // returned value
            if ((typeof(Cordova.callbacks[callbackId]) != 'undefined') 
                && (Cordova.callbacks[callbackId] != null)) {
                if (Cordova.callbacks[callbackId].success) {
                    try {
                        Cordova.callbacks[callbackId].success(v.message);
                    } catch (e) {
                        _consoleLog("Error in success callback: " + callbackId + " = " + e);
                    }

                    // Clear callback if not expecting any more results
                    if (!v.keepCallback) {
                        delete Cordova.callbacks[callbackId];
                    }
                }
            }
            return v.message;
        }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but where is 'v'? "v is null"

Comment: it shows V from some file in http://localhost:8080/apps/services/preview/RQMLight/android/1.0/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js file when i do debug..

Comment: This information looks pretty vital, then, to this error. How about adding the code from that other file that contains 'v'?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that does what you expect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FileReader Example</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    onWLReady = function() {
        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    var wlInitOptions = {
        onSuccess : onWLReady,
        connectOnStartup : false
    };

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload',  function() {
            WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions);
         });
    }

    function log(txt){
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        document.getElementById("log").appendChild(p);
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady(){
        log("onDeviceReady");
    }

    function readFile() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile("ExecutionResult.xml", {
                     create : false, exclusive: false
                },
                function(fileEntry){
                    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                        readDataUrl(file);
                        readAsText(file);
                    },
                    fail);
                },
                fail);
        }, fail);
    }

    function writeFile() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("ExecutionResult.xml", {create: true,     exclusive: true},
                    function(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.createWriter(
                            function(writer) {
                                writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                                    readFile();
                                };
                            writer.onwritestart =     function(evt){
                                    log("onwritestart");
                                };
                                writer.onwrite = function(evt){
                                    log("onwrite");
                                };
                                writer.onerror = function(evt){
                                    log("onerror");
                                };
                                writer.write("JSonData");
                            },
                            fail);
                        }
                        , fail);
            },
            fail);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        log("readDataUrl...");
        reader.onloadstart = function(evt){
            log("onloadstart: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onload = function(evt){
            log("onload: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onloadend = function(evt){
            log("onloadend: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function(evt){
            log("onerror: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        log("readAsText...");
        reader.onloadstart = function(evt){
            log("onloadstart: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onload = function(evt){
            log("onload: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onloadend = function(evt){
            log("onloadend: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function(evt){
            log("onerror: " + evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        log("fail: "+ evt.target.error.code);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body id="content">
    <button onclick="writeFile();">Write and read file</button>
    <p id="log"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...